# Are spontaneous/induced dipoles the same as van der Waals forces?

Tags: dipole, van-der-waals-behavior

I am puzzled by the names of dipoles.

What is the difference among permanent dipoles, spontaneous dipoles, van der Waals forces, and intermolecular forces?

Does "The intermolecular force" imply van der Waals and dipole forces?

Comment: Induced dipoles are created by external electrostatic field. Permanent ones do not need such a field. // *The van der Waals forces  are usually described as a combination of the London dispersion forces between "instantaneously induced dipoles", Debye forces between permanent dipoles and induced dipoles, and the Keesom force between permanent molecular dipoles whose rotational orientations are dynamically averaged over time.* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force

Comment: So, as dipoles are not forces, they cannot be the same as the vdW forces..